# Why do these two Card objects not equate?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, equality

I'm implementing a `Card` object and I'm struggling to understand why my cards equality test fails. Here's the declaration:

```
// card.h
namespace Game {

    class Card {
    public:
        int rank; // 1 to 13
        char suit;

        Card(int r, char s);
        ~Card();
        Card(const Card &other); // copy constructor
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Card &c);
        Card &operator=(const Card &c);
        bool operator>(const Card &other);
        bool operator<(const Card &other);
        bool operator<=(const Card &other);
        bool operator>=(const Card &other);
        bool operator==(const Card &other);
        bool operator!=(const Card &other);
    };

}
```

And the implementation

```
//card.cpp

Game {
    //...

    bool Game::Card::operator==(const Card &other) {
        return (this->rank == other.rank) && (this->suit == other.rank);
    }

    //...
}
```

In my test file, which uses `googletest`

```
// CardTests.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <string>
#include "Card.h"
TEST(CardTests, EqualsOperator) {
    Game::Card fourOfHearts1 = Game::Card(4, 'H');
    Game::Card fourOfHearts2 = Game::Card(4, 'H');
    ASSERT_TRUE(fourOfHearts1 == fourOfHearts2);
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Value of: fourOfHearts1 == fourOfHearts2
  Actual: false
Expected: true
```

Why do the two `fourOfHearts` variables not equate ?

Comment: `this->suit == other.rank` ???

Comment: `return (this->rank == other.rank) && (this->suit == other.rank);` looks wrong. Did you mean `return (this->rank == other.rank) && (this->suit == other.suit);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in `(this->suit == other.rank);` Should be `(this->suit== other.suit);` i guess